# Factory returned value is not displayed

Tags: angularjs

I created a simple factory that returns an array. I set the returned value to a scope value but on the UI I can't see the value.

```
var app = angular.module('so', []);

app.controller('TestCtrl', function($scope, myFactory) {
  $scope.testFactory = [];

  $scope.runFactory = function() {
    $scope.testFactory = myFactory.test();
  }
});

app.factory('myFactory', function() {
  var test = function() {
    var x = [];
    x['FR'] = {
      country: 'France',
      capital: 'Paris'
    };
    console.log(x);
    return x;
  };

  return {
    test: test
  };
});
```

I created a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/6cZ0iBfXSWzh4cBpc1a6) that shows the issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you're using an array as an object (a hash) and not as an array (with elements going from index 0 to N). And that kind of structure is not handled by the `json` filter.

Just use `var x = {};` instead of `var x = [];`, and the value will be displayed as expected.